# Order by performance issue on joined tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables: "Alarms" and "Devices" and a view "vwAlarms"
Alarms Table has 250K rows and Devices Table has only 50 rows.

vwAlarms is just join of two table.

my problems is when i add Top(x) and order by id desc to select * from vwAlarm it takes 10 seconds to execute query. however the same query runs quickly on table Alarm.

```
select * from Alarm --in milliseconds.
select * from vwAlarms --in milliseconds
select top (100) * from Alarms order by id desc --in milliseconds
select top (100) * from vwAlarms order by id desc --takes 10 seconds
```

Here is my view definition:

```
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwAlarms]
AS  SELECT 
    dbo.Devices.Id ,
    dbo.Devices.Name ,
    dbo.Devices.PortsTagPrefix ,
    dbo.Devices.ControlCenterNumber ,
    dbo.Devices.AlarmNumber1 ,
    dbo.Devices.AlarmNumber2 ,
    dbo.Devices.SimCardNumber ,
    dbo.Devices.StationNumber ,
    dbo.Devices.SlaveId ,
    dbo.Devices.TypeId ,
    dbo.Devices.RegionId ,
    dbo.Devices.EnquiryPassword ,
    dbo.Devices.SetupPassword ,
    dbo.Devices.ProtocolId ,
    dbo.Devices.UploadedPacketsCount ,
    dbo.Devices.LastPort ,
    dbo.Devices.LastIp ,
    dbo.Devices.IsForTesting ,
    dbo.Devices.Latitude ,
    dbo.Devices.Longitude ,
    dbo.Devices.X ,
    dbo.Devices.Y ,
    dbo.Devices.MainSchematicId ,
    dbo.Devices.MainTimeChartId ,
    dbo.Devices.MainCategoryChartId ,
    dbo.Alarms.Id ,
    dbo.Alarms.DeviceId ,
    dbo.Alarms.LogId ,
    dbo.Alarms.PortId ,
    dbo.Alarms.TypeId ,
    dbo.Alarms.DateTime ,
    dbo.Alarms.AcknowledgerId ,
    dbo.Alarms.AcknowledgeDateTime ,
    dbo.Alarms.Acknowledged ,
    dbo.Alarms.PortValue
FROM    Devices
        INNER JOIN Alarms ON Devices.Id = Alarms.DeviceId
ORDER BY dbo.Alarms.Id DESC
```

Here is execution plan:
[image]

Warning message of of sort:
[image]

Alarm table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alarms](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LogId] [int] NOT NULL,
[PortId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateTime] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
[AcknowledgerId] [int] NULL,
[AcknowledgeDateTime] [datetime2](0) NULL,
[Acknowledged] [bit] NULL,
[PortValue] [numeric](19, 4) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Alarms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_AlarmTypes] FOREIGN KEY([TypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AlarmTypes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_AlarmTypes]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_Devices] FOREIGN KEY([DeviceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Devices] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_Devices]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_ExtendedUsers] FOREIGN KEY([AcknowledgerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ExtendedUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_ExtendedUsers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alarms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Alarms_Logs] FOREIGN KEY([LogId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Logs] ([Id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER
```

Comment: What do you return from the view? Specifically, is `id` from the `Alarms` or `Devices` table, or something else?

Comment: @Guffa: i return View all columns of both tables. id is from the Alarms Table

Comment: what is the view definition?

Comment: @TToni I've added view definition

Comment: Does Alarms.DeviceId have an index?   Examine a the query plan.

Comment: Also, you are wasting resources returning alarms.deviceID as it has the same value as Devices.ID.  In fact this sort of view seems silly to me, why would you need to have it?

Comment: @HLGEM. tanks for suggestion about DeviceId I've forgot to remove it. Why the view is silly for you :)!? This view is part of other view (vwAlarmPortSetting) in my DataBase

Comment: @Blam, I've updated question with execution plan

Comment: Now I'm really alarmed. Views that call views are often horrible performers and a definite SQL antipattern. It is silly because the code is not so complex it needs to be encapsulated in a view.

Comment: Views should be reserved for complex things that need consistency across the application like financial calcs, they should not be used to save developer time at the cost of performance - performance is critical to database design, saving developer time is a nice to have.

Comment: You can end up generating 10,000,000 records in the background in order to get three at the end. And trust me it is a nightmare to fix a problem in a view that calls a view that calls a view etc. We had some folks use that technique in a database her and the entire application had to be rewritten after it went to production because it couldn't handle production loads. And the final view might join to the same huge table 20 times when it only needd to join once.

Comment: @HLGEM, Thanks for your useful comments, i'll regard them in my project :)

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments

Comment: @HLGEM, one of my views alone itself runs quickly however when i use it in another view it causes performance drop, i'v changed that view and know vwAlarms works well. Thanks, should i mark your comment as answer??

Answer (score 1):

It is not being smart about the sort.
Do you have the FK defined?

I would try all option of the table hints on the join to try and push that sort earlier.

[Join Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)

If table hints does not work I would try a Cross Apply.
I think the Cross Apply should be smart about sort.
But at the cost of not being as fast on the "join".
So it would be good at returning the first 1000 or 10,000 but bad at all.

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2o.*
FROM    t1
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM    t2
        WHERE   t2.t1_id = t1.id
        ) t2o
```

Comment: yes it has FK. see Alarms table definition, let me study Join Hints thanks, i'll come back.

Comment: I've applied joint hints. but didn't get any performance gains

Comment: Is it right decision to create temp table that have last 100 records of Alarms table,and than apply join over it?

Comment: I'm gonna to use temp table and let views go away. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to use a temp to grab the 100 then the join to the small temp should perform fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is using the view a must? If not, you probably should first get your 100 alarms and then join with devices. That's the end result you want right?

Comment: no its not necessary, i think i should you a stored procedure that first select last 100 alarms and store it in temp table that join it and return result. thanks